# boost::dynamic_bitset<> strange behaviour

Tags: c++, boost

i'm trying to encode longitude/latitude with 22 bits and a radius with 20 bits but there is something strange with the radius - see an output below, please...

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cassert>
#include <boost/dynamic_bitset/dynamic_bitset.hpp>
using namespace std;
 
boost::dynamic_bitset<> f2b(int n, float f) {
    assert(sizeof(float) == sizeof(int));
    union {
        float input;
        int output;
    } data;
 
    data.input = f;
    boost::dynamic_bitset<> bits(n, data.output);
                                                                                                               
    return bits;
}
 
int main() {
    // latitude
    cout << f2b(22, (-89.9 + 90) / 180) << '\n';
    // longitude
    cout << f2b(22, (-179.9 + 180) / 360) << '\n';
    // radius
    cout << f2b(20, 10.0) << '\n'; // why this returns '00000000000000000000' ?
 
    return 0;
}

$ ./bits 
0100011010001010110100
0100011010001010110100
00000000000000000000
```

i'd expect a binary representation of 10 which is 00000000000000001010.

Comment: It's undefined behaviour to write a value to one field of a union and then read that value back using a different field of the union. But even if that weren't the case I'm not sure why you are expecting 10. You are interpreting part of the bit pattern of 10.0f as an integer. Why should that give you 10?

Comment: You could do some divide-and-conquer debugging and go a step further -- don't use a `union`, and see if there is a difference.

Comment: Maybe have a look [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754) to understand how floating point numbers are represented at the bit level.

Answer (score 1):

I used this [tool](https://www.h-schmidt.net/FloatConverter/IEEE754.html) to calculate the true bit representation of 10.0f, it's `01000001001000000000000000000000`.

What your code does it return the bottom 20 bits of that which is the `00000000000000000000` that you see.

Now I'd like to explain how to fix your code, but I'm not really sure exactly what you are trying to do. If you can explain I'll do my best to suggest the right way to do it.

Comment: i'm trying to implement a protocol which encodes latitude and longitude with 22 bits based on this formula: my_lat = (lat + 90) / 180 where -90 <= lat <= 90 and my_lon = (lon + 180) / 360 where -180 <= lon <= 180. i also need to encode a radius (in km) with 20 bits. the protocol will transfer a polygons which means many latitude/longitude pairs one by one - so for example [22 bits,22 bits] means a pair of latitude/longitude but in real it will be sequentially:
header: num_of_pair
pair1: [22 bits, 22 bits]
pair2: [22 bits, 22 bits]
.
.
pair(num_of pair) [22 bits, 22 bists]

Answer (score 1):

[SOLVED] never follow customer's specification w/o thinking - it is not possible to encode all float numbers with 20/22 bits (for example 10.0 dec). thanks @john.